# Is loading uniform variables in OpenGL expensive?

Tags: performance, opengl-es, webgl

Typically I load all uniform variables (whether I need to or not) just before I draw a mesh. For example (in WebGL):

```
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.ModelView, false, ModelView.array);
var MVP = Projection.mult(ModelView);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.ModelViewProjection, false, MVP.array);
var NormalMatrix = ModelView.normal();
gl.uniformMatrix3fv(program.NormalMatrix, false, NormalMatrix);
gl.uniform3fv(program.materalDiffuse, materialDiffuse);
gl.uniform3fv(program.materalAmbient, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]);
// ...etc...
// ... draw mesh via gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
```

Some of these uniforms may not have changed since the previous calls to `gl.draw(Arrays|Elements)` so loading them is often redundant. Should I worry about this overhead?

I could add a `dirty` bit to the client variables and only load uniform variables that need to be changed; e.g.:

```
if (ModelView.dirty || Projection.dirty) {
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.ModelView, false, ModelView.array);
   var MVP = Projection.mult(ModelView);
   gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.ModelViewProjection, false, MVP.array);
   ModelView.dirty = Projection.dirty = false;
}
```

I would then set the respective `dirty` bits whenever `ModelView` or `Projection` is mutated.

Is it worth the effort to try and limit uniform variables loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience there is a noticeable overhead for uniform updates in webGL compared to openGL. That being said, you can still expect to be able to do thousands of these uniform updates per second and still hit 60 FPS.

Practically, I think for most applications, uniform updates only become a problem if you are using uniforms as a mean of model instancing. Then you may run into problems due to a combination of uniform update overhead and the number of draw calls required.

Otherwise, I wouldnt worry too much about caching uniforms. It is of course not a bad idea to do so, just dont expect it to be the magic bullet that makes you go from 30 FPS to 60 FPS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by uniforms are not saved. They are saved per program. In fact if you want you could create multiple versions of the same program, each with different uniforms and then just switch programs instead of updating uniforms. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/qp0jyfgv/

Comment: Didnt know that. Edited.